# Matplotlib not showing adequate continuity

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

So I've been trying to understand how MatPlotLib works, so I can display data from a database. I'm currently struggling with what perhaps is an error. Basically the line should drop when the data changes from 3864423 to 3500000 but it doesn't. Here's the code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

dev_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

dev_y = ['3514942', '3524077', '3524077', '3540430', '3540430', '3643543', '3753312', '3864423',
         '3500000', '3990458', '3965666']

plt.plot(dev_x, dev_y)
plt.show()
```

[Here's the image with the graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fonns.png)

I'd like to know why does this occur, and how can I fix it. Also I really want the **Y axis** to look somehow more organized, so it has symmetric steps, such as *3000000-3250000-3500000-etc...*

Comment: You're plotting string values on Y-axis. For matplotlib '3500000' and '3864423' are as different as 'Hello' and 'world' (which would be higher?). Change your values to numeric (int/float)

Comment: okay that definitely did something, but now my Y axis is doing weird steps which I dont know how to change(?) https://gyazo.com/3822740e3ae8200f7e79f0117bfaef6f

Comment: "weird steps"?   What did you want the plot to look like?

Comment: As I said in the last part of the post, I'd like it  to be something like starting at 3000000 then 3250000 then 3500000... and such since this numbers are high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dev_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
dev_y = [3514942, 3524077, 3524077, 3540430, 3540430, 3643543,3753312,3864423, 
         3500000, 3990458, 3965666]

plt.plot(dev_x, dev_y)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') #this to set y-axsis to normal values
plt.ylim([3000000,5000000])
plt.yticks(np.arange(3000000,5000000,250000))
plt.show()
```

Comment: So... yticks is the steps inbetween the ylim? And also, what does normal values mean, string?

Comment: Yes yticks is the steps in between the ylim. As for normal values, it refers to the actual format of the data points, if this line was not added, the y-axis values in this case will be set in logarithmic format.

Comment: I have a few more questions that would need more explanation, can I contact you on discord or somewhere else?